# Is there any difference between male VGA connector with blue or black inside?

Tags: vga, cable, connector

I found two VGA male-to-male cables. I noticed that the connector in one cable has blue color in the background of pins while the other one has black background as shown:
[image]

Is there any difference in terms of the image quality or any?

If we compare with USB connectors, the blue background is better but I cannot find anything on the web about VGA.

Comment: The color of the background is chosen by the vendor. As long as they follow the VGA DE-15 spec you should not see any difference.

Comment: The color inside has no relevance. But you can see the black has one pin (pin 9?) less make sure your monitor does not need it. Regarding image quality don't forget you are talking about VGA so the quality will always be ugly.

Comment: Come on @Robert be reasonable, VGA's 256 color pallet's were like looking into a mirror compared to CGA! :-) VGA's been going strong since 1987 and I'm sure it'll still be so in 2087... assuming civilization somehow holds it together by then. 8-P

Answer (score 1):

The outer connector mold and/or inner insulating mold (around the pins) of VGA cables has (and can still) varied from black, grey, cream, beige, and white (and probably some others) with the outer/inner colors not necessarily matching either. These were typically no more than aesthetic choices depending on the corresponding equipment, and was never indicative of any particular differences between them (specification, performance, quality, etc...).

The only VGA connector color that has ever intended to indicate anything is blue. This basically dates to the introduction of the [VESA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Electronics_Standards_Association) [Display Data Channel (DDC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) standard, which essentially enabled a monitors supported display modes and other paramaters to be communicated to and adjusted from the host machine.

This blue color was to distinguish DDC capable connections from incompatible earlier ones, and was typically present on the outer mold of VGA cable connectors and on the inner insulating mold of surface mounted connectors. This color was then formalized as part of the PC System Design Guide [PC-99 Color-coding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_System_Design_Guide#Color-coding_scheme_for_connectors_and_ports).

In the original IBM implementation pin 9 was 'keyed', meaning female connector hole was plugged/filled in. But with the VESA DDC specification, pin 9 was used as a + 5V DC output to communicate display information (such as resolutions/display name) to the host.

But still not all devices/cables are made the same and so you can find "15 pin" VESA DDC VGA calbes that are actually only 14 pin (like one of yours) that probably came with a device (likely a monitor) that didn't support/need that pin 9 channel/function. However some devices will simply refuse to work without a full 15 pin VGA calbe, and I understand this is the case for a lot of Plasma Screen TV's.

So technically your question is valid... there can be a **STARK** difference in image quality between a 14 and 15 pin VGA cable... depending on the device, you may well have a crisp clear VGA signal beaming through, or you might be limited to a lower resolution as the device cannot detect the max resolution, or they may simply refuse to "handshake" and you wont see anything at all! 8-P

So if in doubt, and you've got low res/no picture, and if the female pin 9 plug isn't keyed (filled in) try a 15 pin VGA cable!

Comment: So, the difference is in the lost pin not in the background color around the pins. Interesting :D
Is this related to some VGA, SVGA, XGA, ... and other abbreviations that a cable is said to support?

Comment: Now you're talking about display resolutions (another aspect/component of the overall VGA* standard/s), the original IBM VGA standard setting a de facto 640x480 resolution, then as technology progressed Super VGA (SVGA) upped the resolution to 800x600, then eXtended Graphics Array (XGA) further increased it to 1024x768 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array#Successors. That progression continued, supporting even FHD resolutions (1920x1080) and ultimately topping out at Quad XGA (QXGA) 2048 x 1536 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#2048_%C3%97_1536_(QXGA).

Comment: But honestly you'd be mad using an analogue (VGA) connector for such high resolutions, when digital standards like HDMI or Display Port will do it SOO much better.

Comment: I just thought it would be like the USB 3 with blue inside as compared to the old one. But it seems that it is not. Thank you anyway for the pin information

Comment: No worries @OsamaEl-Ghonimy! It's always fun to see interesting questions about old school tech. PS: Feel free to accept this as the best answer too if you'd like... :-)